# Segmentation fault due to large 2D array in C++ structure

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct, heap-memory, stack-overflow

I am trying to fix a Segmentation Fault error that occurs when I am running a C++ program which is caused by a structure I am calling to be too large.  I am looking for a way to use my pre-existing C++ structure and move it from the stack to the heap.

My code looks like this:

```
n = 300;

struct arrayStruct {
   double arr[n][n];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   arrayStruct temperature;
   // do a bunch of stuff including passing and receiving the arrayStruct within a few    functions
return 0

}
```

I have tried using malloc and new but only seem to get errors that I have no idea how to fix them.  I've tried within in the structure as well as the main file but can't seem to get it working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot get it to apply to structures.  If I was looking at a simple 2D array that is only defined in a function I would be good.  The problem I have is getting it to a 2D array in a structure.

Comment: Just allocate an instance of `arrayStruct` on the heap: `std::unique_ptr<arrayStruct> temperature(new arrayStruct());`

Answer (score 0):

Try use vector to create 2D array:

```
#include <vector>

 struct arrayStruct {
   arrayStruct()
   : arr(n, std::vector<double>(n))
   {
   }
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate an instance of `arrayStruct` on the heap:

```
std::unique_ptr<arrayStruct> temperature(new arrayStruct());
```

Comment: Ok so the problem with this implementation is that it doesn't seem to initiate the arr.  I get the error: error: conversion from ‘std::unique_ptr<arrayStruct, std::default_delete<arrayStruct> >’ to non-scalar type ‘arrayStruct’ requested